# Angular bootstrap ui timepicker can't find the templates

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I built bootstrap-custom.js build with templates for datepicker, although the file contains templates as follows:

```
angular.module("template/datepicker/datepicker.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/datepicker/datepicker.html",
    "<div ng-switch=\"datepickerMode\" role=\"application\" ng-keydown=\"keydown($event)\">\n" +
    "  <uib-daypicker ng-switch-when=\"day\" tabindex=\"0\"></uib-daypicker>\n" +
    "  <uib-monthpicker ng-switch-when=\"month\" tabindex=\"0\"></uib-monthpicker>\n" +
    "  <uib-yearpicker ng-switch-when=\"year\" tabindex=\"0\"></uib-yearpicker>\n" +
    "</div>");
}]);
```

I am calling this js. file correctly from my index.html, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: template/datepicker/datepicker.html
```

I assume I have to change the path for it, but what do I have to change in order to refer to the templates correctly?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT 1**

bootstrap-custom.js

```
angular.module("ui.bootstrap.tpls", ["template/datepicker/datepicker.html","template/datepicker/day.html","template/datepicker/month.html","template/datepicker/popup.html","template/datepicker/year.html","template/timepicker/timepicker.html"]);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.datepicker', ['ui.bootstrap.dateparser', 'ui.bootstrap.position'])
```

Comment: Are you including module `template/datepicker/datepicker.html` in your parent module where directive (I assume it's directive) calls for the partial? `templateUrl` should be exactly how you put it in cache: `$templateCache.put("template/datepicker/datepicker.html",`

Comment: So this module is included in the bootstrap.js file, which is called from my page, now the bootstrap.js file is a custom built which is the module "ui.bootstrap.datepicker" and yes this last one is included in my main module, do I have to include "template/datepicker/datepicker.html" and any other module representing templates as well?

Comment: @maurycy check EDIT 1. Given that, I am only including ui.bootstrap.datepicker in my main module.

Comment: I have included "ui.bootstrap.tpls" which itself includes all the ".html" in my main module and now it works. Please put it in an answer so I can mark is as solution.

Comment: Happy to help, i'll put that in answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks that my guess from first comment was correct

since you define the template as different module you need to include that module directly or indirectly (through other module) into your main app

#### direct include

```
angular.module("myUberApp", ["template/datepicker/datepicker.html"]);
```

#### indirect include

```
angular.module("myUberApp", ["myOtherModule"]);
angular.module("myOtherModule", ["template/datepicker/datepicker.html"]);
```